# How to use ASP.NET Web routing and sitemap

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sitemap

I have this in my `global.asax`

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)

End Sub

Protected Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)

    ...        
    routes.MapPageRoute("aboutusRoute", "aboutus", "~/aboutus.aspx", True)
    routes.MapPageRoute("indexRoute", "index", "~/index.html", True)

    routes.MapPageRoute("archiveRoute", "archive/{year}/{month}","~/archive.aspx",True)
End Sub
```

Then in my Masterpage i have the following markup

```
<asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 5px" ParentLevelsDisplayed="2" SiteMapProvider="SiteMapLinks">
                                    <PathSeparatorTemplate>
                                        <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="/chuktex/Images/Seperator.png"  style="margin-right:5px"/></PathSeparatorTemplate>
                                </asp:SiteMapPath>
                                <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
```

And in my `web.sitemap` i have the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >

    <siteMapNode url="~/home" title="Home"  description="Home">
      .
      .
      .
       <siteMapNode url="~/systemmaint/" title="System Maintainance"  description="System Maintainance" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/Login/" title="Login"  description="Login" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/Profile/" title="Profile"  description="Profile" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/archive/" title="Archive"  description="Archive" />
      .
      .
      .
    </siteMapNode>

</siteMap>
```

if i click on link to systemmaint the siteMapPath worked correctly but if i click on archive link nothing came up please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving default values to parameters "year" and "month" in global.asax using RouteValueDictionary. Please check the following article for more details:

http://karmic-development.blogspot.in/2013/10/url-routing-in-aspnet-web-forms-part-2.html

Moreover, in case you have included some javascript file in the page, normal src value may not work. You need to provide src of the javascript file as

```
src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/resource/lightbox_plus_min.js") %>'
```

Thanks & Regards,
Munjal